# How to configure robots.txt for allow few pages?

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt

I have website called  www.example.com - where it is landing page only. - its html website.

On that page there is button called "CLiCK WEBSITE" - where my actual website is located.  so on url it should look like www.example.com/originalwebsite - its wordpress website.

Now i want to crawl only some of the page of my "orignialwebsite" wordpresssite
www.example.com/originalwebsite/page1/, www.example.com/originalwebsite/page2/, www.example.com/originalwebsite/page3/ and also of course home page - html page

So, what should be the robots.txt?

Answer (score 3):

Robots.txt is primarily used by law abiding search engine crawlers to identify sections of your website which aren't supposed to be indexed or crawled. So, rather than thinking about "What to Allow" think about "What to Disallow".

Technically, you can disallow your `JS, CSS or Config files/folder` which doesn't need to show in search results.

**Telling search spiders to stop crawling** and indexing do this

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /
```

**Telling search engines not to crawl/index few sections** do this

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /js/
Disallow: /css/
Disallow: /wp-config.php
```

**Wordpress Robots.txt example**

```
User-Agent: *
Allow: /wp-content/uploads/
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /readme.html
```

If crawlers find a link or reference to a page they will crawl it unless it's denied in Robots.txt

Comment: 1> www.xyz.com - HTML landing page - want to crawl 2> www.xyz.com/originalwebsite/ - WP website- dont want to crawl 3> www.xyz.com/originalwebsite/page1/, page2/, page3/ -WP website pages- want to crawl

Answer (score -1):

http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

The link above should tell you how to do this. (Scroll down almost all the way)

PLEASE google it BEFORE you go to Stack Overflow!

> To exclude all files except one
>
> This is currently a bit awkward, as there is no "Allow" field. The
>   easy way is to put all files to be disallowed into a separate
>   directory, say "stuff", and leave the one file in the level above this directory:
>
> ```
> User-agent: * 
> Disallow: /~joe/stuff/
> ```

Comment: i read before i post, but couldn't get that's why i posted hear. If you know then please give answer related to question. Thank You!

Comment: Either I don't understand your question, or your question is not properly worded. The website shows everything that needs to be in the website. You either need to explicitly list all websites except for the ones you want to robots to access, or use a separate directory.

Comment: 1> www.xyz.com - HTML landing page - want to crawl  2>  www.xyz.com/originalwebsite/ - WP website- dont want to crawl 3>  www.xyz.com/originalwebsite/page1/, page2/, page3/ -WP website pages- want to crawl

Comment: should i write like below:                                                                    User-agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: /example/

Allow: http://www.example.com/originalwebsite/page1/
Allow: http://www.example.com/originalwebsite/page2/
Allow: http://www.example.com/originalwebsite/page3/  (note: i disallow the wp website, but these are the wp website pages i want to crawl)

Comment: Disallow:/originalwebsite/page1/
Disallow: /page2/
Disallow: /page3/